# instantiate the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DropDown interface and insert in the table cell range

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I am doing an automation project,In that doing read and write the word doc from windows application using c#, I am trying to insert DropDown control in the table cell(word template) dynamically in the run time.

But I am  unable instantiate the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DropDown` interface and insert in the table cell range.

```
    var applicationWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    applicationWord.Visible = false;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
    doc = applicationWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref  missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    doc.Activate();
    applicationWord.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

    Word.Table table8 = doc.Tables[8];

    Word.Range tablerng = table8.Range;
    Word.Range rnd = table8.Cell(1, 1).Range;
    int tablerowsCount = table8.Rows.Count;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DropDown drd = **?**
```